# Python or linux command line detect directory name in .tar.gz

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm automating a process to upload files and work with them in AWS. I have a python script and I upload `somefolder.tar.gz`. Typically these files just extract a folder named `somefolder` but sometimes it is different folder name. Is there anyway to detect what the folder will be named on extraction?

Currently I am performing the extraction through the boto protocol:

```
output = ssh_client.run('cd ~/Sharing && tar -zxvf ' + tar_filename)
```

tar_filename is something like: `filename.tar.gz` One solution could be to just chop the `.tar.gz` and make sure all the extracted folders are always named the same as the .tar.gz

Comment: This is not too easy, since there may be no folder at all, or many folders. If you want to make sure, better create a folder yourself and unpack it _into_ that folder.

Comment: you use `-t` to list the contents before you extract it ?

Comment: Hmmm, good call @Ctx maybe my script should take the path to the directory of files and create the .tar.gz itself so it knows the name on upload and unzip

Comment: You can extract files to a destination directory like this:
`output = ssh_client.run("cd ~/Sharing && tar -zxvf " + tar_filename + " -C " +  tar_filename.strip('.tar.gz') + "/")`

Comment: @vrs, does this leave the unknown tar foldername as a subfolder in the new directory that I create with -C?

Comment: @vrs I tested and this seems like a simple and working solution!

Comment: @wprins yes, it does. If a tar archive contains directory, then the above command will extract it into `filename` directory, so they will be nested.

Comment: One more quick question for you: when I do `tar_filename = test.tar.gz` and I do `tar_filename.strip('.tar.gz')` my result is a string `es` ... whats going on here?

Comment: @wprins oops, my bad. Instead of `strip` use something like this: `tar_filename.replace('.tar.gz', '')` or `tar_filename.split('.tar.gz')[0]`. Also, please use hashtag with @username, when replying to a comment, otherwise he/she won't be able to see your comment in the inbox

Answer (score 3):

tar -tf will list all the files in the tar, without extracting.

You can then parse the output to find what the top-level directory is.

Answer (score 2):

Can you examine the file contents before you upload file to AWS? If you can, you just list the contents with `tzf` parameters to make sure the naming is correct, or you can do the same thing with built-in python [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can list the content of a tar.gz with the command tar --list -f your_file.tar.gz